# VSCode reloads Java projects on each startup which takes a very long time

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I am in the process of switching from Eclipse to VSCode for Java Development - so far, I have been able to setup a workspace folder with all my Java projects in it and all works fine.

However, every time I restart VSCode, all projects are rebuilding (showing me "Opening Java Projects: check details") which takes a very long time (about 5 minutes) - in comparision, when I am re-opening my Eclipse workspace with the same amount of projects, it only takes ~30 seconds for everything to be ready. Is there something I am doing wrong or can't VSCode "remember" Java projects as good as Eclipse?

Comment: Is the 'auto-build' turned off in your eclipse?

Comment: No, it's turned on.

Comment: **Ctrl+Shift+P** Open the command palette and select `Java:Clean Java Language Server Workspace`. If the problem persists, try reinstalling vscode.

Comment: That only restarts the process of importing Java projects which is performed on each startup of VScode and takes very long for multiple large projects. I am curious why VSCode is so inefficient on a restart, when both Eclipse and IntelliJ are much more efficient in that regard (for Java projects at least).

Comment: @infochip. I've opened an [issue](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/2643) on GitHub, hope it's useful to you.

Comment: I face the same problem. Any update?

Answer (score 8):

You probably have this Java Red Hat plugin. Switch to pre-release version. It fixes this issue:

[image]

Comment: I'm on pre-release and its still taking forever. Much more than 5 minutes.

Comment: I would have to test this out again on my current CPU. Not sure what version you have trevor4n. Also look at the suggestions above that are listed in the comments below the question.

Comment: Are pre-release versions guaranteed to be stable?

Comment: Not entirely. But this one should be well vetted by now.